# Scala REPL: find where given class / trait is defined

Tags: scala

Note: the following discussion applies only to the REPL.

If I don't know the full package name for some given class, IDEs such as Eclipse or Netbeans will helpfully tell me the possible paths where the class is defined.

Example I have some class `foo.somePackage.someClass` defined in a jar that I drop into `SCALA_HOME\lib` directory. Now when I do `val a = new someClass`, Scala cannot find the class. I need to do an explicit `import foo.somePackage.someClass`.

Is it possible to find all the places where `someClass` is defined without having to know it beforehand?

Answer (score 3):

As I know, It's impossible in pure Scala REPL.
IntelliJ IDEA Scala Console can auto-import necessary classes http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/10/19/scala-language-console-nika-builds/

Comment: I guess that in the question "only in the REPL" means "only on the native scala REPl", not the one embedded in an IDE.

Comment: If there is no other solution may be this will be useful